# Graphics lib for 'SVG Editor'

Tags: java, graphics, svg

I want to create my own SVG Editor on Java. Suggest good library for this. Please. It library should be simple and fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/svg/)
may be helpfull